# How do I re-nest an object into an array of objects in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to sort items that point to another item to be nested under the item it points to. Each item could have a reference to a parent; if it does nest it under it's parent else re-index normally.

```
foreach($list as $item) {
  if($item->parent != null) {
    $newlist[$list->parent] = $item;
  }
  else {
    $newlist[$item->id] = $item;
  }
}
```

Using the equals operator overries the item rather then append to an array. Ideally is should convert the $newlist[$item->parent] to an array of new items.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `$list` and the `$newlist` you would want created?

Comment: Try `$newlist[$list->parent][] = $item;`. The `[]` pushes the item on the end of the array `$newlist[$list->parent]`. You should ensure this is an empty array if it does not already exist, although PHP will cope with it if you don't - it'll raise a warning though, and you should aim to have zero of those.

Comment: Yeah, when I used the extra brackets it gave me an error. The problem I was getting was from when I tried reading the output to verify it was added to the $newlist. Was trying to treat an object like an array.